# marquee unable to pass w3 validator

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c-validation

I having the xhtml checkup error as below. Please help.

Error Line 217, Column 16: there is no attribute "style"

Error Line 217, Column 64: there is no attribute "behavior"
…tyle=" border-width:4; border-style:solid;" behavior="scroll" direction="left"

Error Line 217, Column 83: there is no attribute "direction"
…tyle=" border-width:4; border-style:solid;" behavior="scroll" direction="left"

Comment: We can not suggest anything without seeing the HTML code in question (posting the line in question should be enough)

Comment: The html code is <marquee style=" border-width:4; border-style:solid;" behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="5">

Comment: Trust me, you don't want to be caught dead using marquees...those are so 90s.  Unless you were told specifically to do EXACTLY that...

Comment: Try <marquee></marquee> without any style and then check w3 Validator this will give you an idea whether style is giving error or marquee id giving error.

Comment: @levininja then anyway can replace marquees?

Comment: @rohitr if only <marquee></marquee>, after validated also have error > Error Line 1, Column 1: no document type declaration; will parse without validation <marquee></marquee>

Comment: @Pekka웃 where can find the javascript code?

Comment: Thanks Guys for yours replied, I found a way to pass marquee from w3 validation which use php code to call the marquee =)

Answer (score 1):

The `marquee` element is invalid in any published version of HTML. It is not even described in any version except HTML5 drafts, and they explicitly declare it non-conforming (invalid), and [they say](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0): “CSS transitions and animations are a more appropriate mechanism.”

If you wish to validate a document using `marquee`, you would need to use a [custom DTD](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/own-dtd.htm) or a special-purpose checker. (This would of course make the document conform to some published HTML specification; it would just let you detect unintentional misspellings, wrong nesting, etc., which is what validation is really meant for.)